# How create a cocoapod library

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, xcode9.3

[image]

My dilemma is stupid but I do not know what to do, basically I do not know if what I show in the image refers to the platform for which you want to develop or to the platform in which you are going to develop

Comment: It's probably better to copy/paste the terminal output and format it as code next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the platform for which you are targeting the cocoapod. So if you are making a cocoapod to be used in iOS apps, choose **iOS**.

If only we could use iOS to build a cocoapod for iOS... ;]

Comment: sorry i don't know how can do that, If I have not accepted your answer, explain how I can do it, I think that I already accept it, anyway you let me know if I did it or not

Answer (score 0):

sorry i don't know how can do that, If I have not accepted your answer, explain how I can do it, I think that I already accept it, anyway you let me know if I did it or not